# Group by working in SQL Server 2000 but not in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

I used following query in SQL Server 2000

```
SELECT 
   U.FirstName,
   SUM(VE.Score)AS Score, SUM(VE.QuizTime) AS Time, 
   SUM(VE.IsQuizType) AS QuizesAttempted,
   SUM(VE.IsProgrammingType) AS ProgrammingProblemsAttempted 
from 
    Users U INNER JOIN VirtualExercise VE on U.UserID=VE.UserID 
where U.UserID IN( 10,11 ) AND ProgramID = 2 
group by U.FirstName 
order by VE.Score desc
```

It working fine in SQL Server 2000 but not working in SQL Server 2005.
Gives following error:

> Column "VirtualExercise.Score" is
>   invalid in the ORDER BY clause because
>   it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause. --- Inner Exception

Please help...

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server 2005 is correct: you are trying to order by a value that doesn't exist in the output because you must either GROUP on it or aggregate it. `VE.Score` is neither. SQL Server 2000 allowed some ambiguities like this (edit: see "ORDER BY clause" at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143359(SQL.90).aspx for info on this)

I assume you mean

```
ORDER BY SUM(VE.Score) DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2000 is kind of dumb where it comes to table and column aliases in the result set. Provided an explicit alias column is introduced (e.g. `Score` in your case, `Col3` in the example below), it doesn't matter what table alias you use in the ORDER BY clause:

```
create table #T1 (
    ID int not null primary key,
    Col1 varchar(10) not null
)
go
create table #T2 (
    ID int not null primary key,
    Col2 varchar(10) not null
)
go
insert into #T1 (ID,Col1)
select 1,'abc' union all
select 2,'def'
go
insert into #T2 (ID,Col2)
select 1,'zyx' union all
select 2,'wvu'
go
select *,1 as Col3 from #T1 t1 inner join #T2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID order by t2.Col3
```

Since you presumably want to sort by the computed `Score` column, just remove the `VE.` prefix.

Comment: yep, this what I was referring too http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143359(SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since you have defined `SUM(VE.Score)AS Score` in select , do you mean `ORDER BY Score DESC`

Comment: but my query running perfectly in SQL Server 2000. Its only give error in SSQL Server 2005.